# Array / List / collection of objects of a class in R

Tags: r, oop

I am a beginner with OOP in R and am stuck at a problem for which I can find no solution.

I defined a class "node" in R using setClass that contains information about a "node" in a network -

```
setClass(Class = "node", 
    representation = representation(nID = "integer", links = "integer", 
        capacity = "numeric"), 
    prototype = prototype(nID = integer(1), links = integer(20), 
        capacity = numeric(20)))
```

What I really want to do is create an array/list that holds several "nodes", each of which is of class "node". Something like

```
nodeID[100] <- new("node")
```

But that clearly doesnt work. I have tried creating arrays and converting their class to "node" but that didnt do it either.

This will help me do things like loop over all nodes in my system-

```
for(i in 1:dim(nodeID))
{
    nodeID[i]@capacity <- 1000
    blah blah....
}
```

Note that the problem isnt initializing/defaulting the value of slots (e.g. capacity in this case). I can do that. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks,

Sumit

Answer ----

Thanks @Ricardo and @dickoa. This created the list of nodeID just like I wanted .

Want to add for anyone else facing the same problem that in order to access the elements/slots of the list of class "node" you have to use the following:

```
nodeID[[1]]@capacity[1]
```

Also, I will use lapply instead of for.

Sumit

Comment: More a comment than an answer, but you're much better off thinking in vectors, and thinking of 'node' as actually a collection of nodes, so `nodeId@capacity = replicate(100, 1000))` and so on. One only has one class instance for 100 nodes, instead of 100 node instances. It is analogous to creating one data.frame, rather than 100, with similar performance consequences.

Comment: @MartinMorgan I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `replicate`

```
nodeID <- replicate(100, new("node"), simplify="list")
is(nodeID)
# [1] "list"   "vector"
is(nodeID[[1]])
# [1] "node"
```

---

Using something like `nodeID[100] <- new("node")` as you found, does not work.   What that (is attempting) to do is look for an object called `nodeID` and if found, try to set its 100th element to `new("node")`. 
It does not, say, create an object `nodeID` and populate it with 100 elements.

---

Also, notice that you can avoid your `for` loop by instead using, say, `lapply`: 
eg, instead of:

```
for(i in 1:dim(nodeID))
{
 nodeID[i]@capacity <- 1000
 blah blah....
}
```

use:

```
lapply(nodeID, function(n) {blah balh...} )
```

Comment: +1 beat me by a sec with same answer, I just added `simplify = list`

Comment: @dickoa, good call on using simplify.  I added that in to be explicit for other situations. But for the OP, I dont think the give nodes could  be reduced to array